# Uniting list of elements to one table row in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to React.

I have a `MonthEntry` component containing a list of 1 or more instances of `MonthPlanEntry`. I want to display all the `MonthPlanEntry` in the list as a single table row.

```
class MonthPlanEntry extends React.Component {
    constructor(remaining_loan, interest, loan_reduce) {
        this.remaining_loan = remaining_loan;
        this.interest = interest;
        this.loan_reduce = loan_reduce;
    }
}

class MonthEntry extends React.Component {
    constructor(plans) {
        this.plans = plans;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                this.plans.map((plan, key) => {
                    <td>{plan.remaining_loan}</td>
                    <td>{plan.interest}</td>
                    <td>{plan.loan_reduce}</td>
                });
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is that every time I try to do something with the list I get an error: `JSX expressions must have one parent element.ts(2657)`

**Edit:**

To clarify - I want the `MonthEntry` to return a single `<tr>` composed of multiple `MonthPlanEntry`s. Each `MonthPlanEntry` will add 3 `<td>`s to the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `td` tags with a `React.Fragment` and wrap the whole component inside a `tr`

```
    return (
        <tr>
            {this.plans.map((plan, key) => {
                <React.Fragment>
                   <td>{plan.remaining_loan}</td>
                   <td>{plan.interest}</td>
                   <td>{plan.loan_reduce}</td>
                </React.Fragment>
            });}
        </tr>
    );
```

Comment: Very useful! Though you probably mean that instead of <tr> I will add <React.Fragment>. Found this thanks to your pointer https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html. This is exactly the case I am describing.